# What is my net salary on a gross salary of 3,000 EUR in Holland? Can I live on that in Amsterdam?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, salary, cost-of-living

I am a non-EEA citizen. I just got a job offer in Amsterdam with a monthly salary of€3,000 before tax. How much will I get per month? Is that enough for typical costs of living, i.e. food and board for just myself?

#### Update

This is the pic that I found:

[image]

Will I have to pay 40% tax on an annual salary of €36,000?

**Sorry for the silly questions, but really in my country we don't have income tax.**

Comment: Compare with your city http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/comparison.jsp. And tax calculator http://thetax.nl/?salary=32000&ruling=0&socialSecurity=0&year=2016&allowance=1

Comment: @EugenMartynov my country is not in the list. I need to know how much I take per month (the net ) so i can know if I am able to rent a room and live with that money or not.

Comment: Check the second link

Comment: @EugenMartynov are you sure of that link for the tax please? they told me that I have to pay 42% of my salary as taxes. but i don't know. is there any official document for the tax?

Comment: Here are tax wages http://www.expatax.nl/tax-rates-2016.php

Comment: @EugenMartynov thank you, please could you check the updated questions.

Comment: It's difficult to guess what your expectations are but it's slightly more than the average wage, twice the minimum wage so it should be enough to put food on the table (and do a few other things too). But it's not a very high salary either and accommodation will eat a big part of your budget.

Comment: Regarding taxes and statutory insurance contributions, it's more complicated than that. The correct way to read the table is that you pay 36.55% on the first €19,922 and 40,40% on the rest (that's how tax brackets work everywhere). But there are several complications, in fact you would not pay any taxes on the first €1500 ([formula over here](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/inkomstenbelasting/heffingskortingen_boxen_tarieven/heffingskortingen/algemene_heffingskorting/algemene_heffingskorting_inkomensafhankelijk/tabel_ahk_2016))

Comment: And then you would qualify for at least one other tax credit (because you would be working). It's only for the income above these tax credit thresholds that the tax rates you found kick in. So you're better off using a simulator to figure all this out. Assuming you don't have any other income (including no end-of-the-year allowance, properties abroad, etc.) and do not qualify for any other special credit, [this simulator](http://www.loonwijzer.nl/home/salaris/brutonetto) suggests that €3000 translates to about €2200 after taxes per month (effective tax rate a bit over 25%).

Comment: @Gala obvious you're an expert in these stuff, while I don't know any thing in it. So i really appreciate if you can help me. first of all, you sent this page http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/inkomstenbelasting/heffingskortingen_boxen_tarieven/heffingskortingen/algemene_heffingskorting/algemene_heffingskorting_inkomensafhankelijk/tabel_ahk_2016 but do you have it in english?

Comment: @Gala second, you sent this page, http://www.loonwijzer.nl/home/salaris/brutonetto do you have it in enlighs ?

Comment: @Gala third, are you telling me that this page is true ? http://thetax.nl/?salary=38000&ruling=0&socialSecurity=0&year=2016&allowance=1 and by true i mean the calculation is correct?

Comment: @Gala fourth, in your last comment you assumed that i don't have annual allowance, but in the contract, it is written, *You will receive an annual holiday allowance of 8% of your gross annual base salary (in the case of non-complete years, calculated pro rata).* will have help you to give me a better value for my net salary please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42089/discussion-between-gala-and-anastasie-laurent).

Answer (score 8):

The proposed salary is almost spot on what is referred to as 'modaal inkomen', or the median income: the most common income in the country. Therefore, you should be able to live on this salary just fine! But it really all depends on your lifestyle, of course.

Keep in mind there are other things that will be taken out of your salary too, like in most countries. But you may also be eligible for tax deductions and other benefits provided by the state.

Now, if you're asking about the applicable income tax rate, here is how the system works in the Netherlands and most other countries that have bracketed tax systems:

- You get 36,000 euros per year.
- The amount up to 19,922 euros is taxed at 36.55% = 7,281.
- The amount above 19,922 euros and until 66,421 is taxed at 40.4% = 6,495.
- You would be left with 1,852 euros per month to live on.

I am a Dutch citizen, but live elsewhere. I remember the rate of 42%, which you mentioned in a comment to @EugonMartynov. I think this tool may still be using outdated rates, as the rates mentioned on the [Tax and Customs Administration (Belastingdienst)](http://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/inkomstenbelasting/heffingskortingen_boxen_tarieven/boxen_en_tarieven/overzicht_tarieven_en_schijven/u_hebt_in_2016_de_aow_leeftijd_nog_niet_bereikt) website are different. I have used these ones in my calculation.

Comment: thank you, you are telling me that the net salary will be 1800 while the other user said a number betwee 2200 and 2500, the difference between you two is too big. Plus, do you thing 1800 is enough in Amsterdam please? i have to rent a room myself. i am a very active person for concerts, operas, parties ....

Comment: There might be tax breaks I did not factor in. As I said, these are just the rates I found online and other aspects will impact. Surely your prospective employer would be able to tell you the net transfer every month?! I left NL over 10 years ago. I'm not particularly qualified to tell you how far such a salary takes you. But simply by it being "the national median salary" I would imagine it's possible!?

Comment: The mode and median are not the same and a quick search yesterday suggested this salary was above the *average* (which is typically higher than either the mode and median in this case). It's possible I got my stats wrong, where did you find yours? Also your calculation is off, you're forgetting the tax credits (at least the *Algemene heffingskorting* and the *Arbeidskorting* should apply).

Comment: @RobdeJonge thanks for answering, i am optimistic about the salary because even if it is not too much, but saving 10% of it in NL is better than saving 10% of the *medium incom* in another country, such as Spain or Italy. In this 10% in NL, i may be able to have a holiday in another country. If I am wrong, let me know please. I'm just afraid of the accomodation, for the food i can cook and manage myself, but i need a funished, *good* (more or less) room

Comment: Like I said, there might be benefits and further charges which may apply. I left over a decade ago. I got the modaal inkomen for 2016 from https://nl.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modaal_inkomen.

Comment: @RobdeJonge OK, thanks! I understand my confusion now: I was looking at the average income per capita, not the modal salary.

Comment: so what did you sum up guys? is my salary above the average ?

Comment: It's about "modaal". I don't know how that compares to the average. And I don't know the English term for modaal :) in NL, "modaal" is what gets used rather than average. Having a modaal income means half of the population makes more than you and half of the population makes less than you.

Comment: @RobdeJonge thank you, i got the idea, but i am still confused, i see that you all did what you could to help me, but i am still not able to figure out how much i need per month, and how much exactly my net salary will be. i will contact the company again.

Comment: How much you need, as mentioned, depends on your lifestyle choices. I think you can assume to have an "average" life on this salary! If half the country can make due on less, then for sure you can have an ok life on this salary?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent & RobdeJonge The English term for modaal is modal (from the statistical mode) but that's not what I was confused about. The €27000 figure is average income per capita (counting other type of income but also children and dependents in the denominator), €36000 is the modal salary (counting only people who are employed). Either way, Rob is right it's a “normal” salary, not particularly high but many people live on that or less so you can have a decent life with it (meaning rent, going out from time to time, a vacation per year but not fancy restaurants and opera every week).

Comment: @Gala, RobdeJonge: if *modaal* means that 50% have more and 50% have less, then the English translation is *median.*

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's the definition of the median but *modaal* really means mode (and as I wrote earlier, with a right-skewed distributions like income, you would expect the median to be higher and the arithmetic mean to be higher still). Median is *mediaan* in Dutch.

Comment: @Gala so do we know whether 36K is the median or the modal figure, orhow different the median and the mode are in this case?

Comment: @phoog I have some trouble finding out, it turns out this “modaal inkomen” isn't any of these but an abstraction computed as a percentage of the mean income!? Also most statistics are about disposable income per household, not pre-tax salaries. The median disposable income per household (without any correction for the size of the household) was 28.7k in 2014, the average 34.2k. That would be the OP's salary below the median (not so however if you apply the correction for household size).

Comment: Just that it's the modal income doesn't automatically mean that you can live well on it 1) on your own and 2) in Amsterdam.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich depends on your definition of living well, as has been covered numerous times. I lived in Amsterdam below modal and I lived in Amsterdam making double modal. Different lives. All about your own decisions.

Comment: @RobdeJonge: I just mean that Amsterdam is more expensive than the rest of the country, so being modal nationally probably means you're below modal in Amsterdam.

Answer (score 6):

You would be able to get by, but not save anything, I would think. As of 2018, I live alone, my salary is ~3,850 before taxes (not counting an annual allowance/bonus/vacation pay/etc.), I enjoy the 30% ruling, and manage to save about 1,000 EUR per month or so, ignoring large unforeseen expenses. I rent a 1.5-bedroom apartment for 1,275 EUR a month, ride a bike to work, and I'm pretty frugal in my expenses (I think), except for a visit to my home country every few months. Adjusting for your details would bring me to just about breaking even.

Of course, that would not really be sustainable for the long term, since occasionally you have larger expenses; and you probably want to save money for when you go back home, or want to by a house/apartment etc. So, for now, I would suggest sharing a flat with someone. That would not only reduce your rent, but also your bills - and would allow you more freedom of choice with respect to the region in which you live.

Good luck and welcome!

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on how cheap an apartment you'll manage to find. Your salary is low (about 1,800 Euro/month), which gives you little flexibility. AFAIK the cost of renting a flat in Amsterdam is over 1,000 Euros (http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=Netherlands&city=Amsterdam confirms that), but there are always some cheaper occasions. However, if you look in nearby cities like Haarlem, you should be able to manage it to have some money for extra expenses and even put something aside.

But you need to stay somewhere during the apartment search, and your salary doesn't give you any reserve for that, you should ask your company for support.

The decision is up to you, but you should expect to live rather sparingly on that salary, unless you'll manage to save on renting, for example renting a bigger apartment with 2-3 other people and share the costs.

Comment: Thanks for answering, when you said 1000, did you mean an apartment or a room in an apartment ?

Comment: An appartment. Room would be cheaper, but harder to get for a foreigner.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo: Rooms are not hard to get for foreigners in Amsterdam, in my experience.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that the travel time between Haarlem station and Amsterdam Centraal is 15 to 20 minutes. Depending on the specific locations of one's home and office, a commute between Harlem and Amsterdam could be quicker than the average intraurban commute in many large cities like London and New York.

Comment: Needless to say, 1800 euros per month is a joke.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Why is that a joke?